# WPF DatePicker Custom Format

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, datepicker

As mentioned I am looking to customize the datepicker dates to YYYY-MM-DD
I have in my XAML file:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DatePicker_Date"  Width="300px" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                    <DatePicker.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                                 Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, 
                                        StringFormat={x:Static local:App.DateFormat}}" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DatePicker.Resources>
                </DatePicker>
```

And then in my App.xaml.cs file I have:

```
 public partial class App : Application
{
    public static string DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
}
```

So this works to display the date the proper way within the picker itself but when I go to reference that date :

```
string dateTemp = DatePicker_Date.Text;
```

It just prints out the original date format MM-DD-YYYY

What am I missing here -- I can't use PART_Textbox.text that isn't working. How can I get that newly formatted text into a string?

I have followed a few of these solutions on stack overflow but they seem to have same result, the one I like best is set in app.xaml resources so I don't have to do it everytime for each date picker within my application but I have same issue:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
 <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
 <Setter Property="Control.Template">
     <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
             <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
        Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd.MM.yyyy', 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
         </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
```

Relatively new to WPF apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: See the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker.text?view=windowsdesktop-6.0): "*While the Text property can be set to any string that can be parsed by the Parse method date, the format of the string that is returned depends on the value of the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture property. This means that the DatePicker might display a string that is different than what the user typed.*" - You have to format the SelectedDate property yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the currently selected date as a `DateTime` using the `SelectedDate` property and then format it according to your specific format:

```
string dateTemp = DatePicker_Date.SelectedDate?.ToString(App.DateFormat);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for me!